# Two different pages with distinct headers and footers in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

Right so I'm fairly new to this crystal reports thing and i've been stuck with this for days and can't get my head around it!

i have to produce a report which contains two pages - 1. purchase order and 2. receiving note

report 1. has its own 
header
detail
footer

report 2 has distincts header, detail and footer.

the only way i managed to make this happen was to  use subreports but they only work in 1 level deep so having the addresses in subreports themselves i can't use this!

Now ive tried creating new groups and all of that but i cant get it to show in different pages

right now i have

header1
header2 
details1
details2
footer1
footer2

any ideas of what could i do please?

Comment: What are you unable to show in different pages?

Comment: You won't be able to separate the Details section between two pages like that. I would stick with using a subreport; can you explain your issues with doing that a little more clearly?

Answer (score 0):

If you know that page 1 and 2 are always page 1 and 2 (and a page 1 doesn't spill over into the 2nd page pushing the original 2nd page out to the 3rd page) then you can use a formula to change the header based on the page number.  Create a new formula and then you can do something like this:

Basic Syntax

```
If PageNumber = 1 Then
    formula = "This is the page header for page 1"
ElseIf PageNumber = 2 Then
    formula = "This is the page header for page 2"
End If
```

That said, I probably would probably stick to using sub reports and use the report headers in those reports to display your unique headings.  Using the section expert you can make sure that there is a page break between the two sub reports.